# Is it possible to run an EXE through Windows Service using WIX without creating a Service project?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-services, windows-installer, wix3.10

I have this mosquitto.exe which I need to install as a Windows Service using WiX. When I create a Windows Service project and run the EXE through its start method everything works fine. But is it possible to run the mosquitto.exe using only the ServiceControl and ServiceInstall lines and without having a separate Windows Service project? I tried this but the Service fails to start though it isntalls fine.

```
 </Component>
  <Component Id="cmp59455E1C37B7879C4BC250DE3D60A2AD" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="179B4F4C-912B-4CA1-8F08-5E1B4ADFFD8B" Win64="no">
    <File Id="fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto.exe" />
   <ServiceInstall Id="MosquittoSI" Type="ownProcess" Name="Mosquitto" DisplayName="Mosquitto" Description="Mosquitto broker service" Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem"  ErrorControl="normal"/>
 <ServiceControl Id="MosquittoSC" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="Mosquitto" Wait="no" />  
</Component>
```

Have I done something wrong here or do I really need to launch this mosquitto.exe through an another exe created using a Windows Service project? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When dealing with Windows services, the Windows event log is the place to look. Both the standard logs, which would tell you a service failed to start and any custom log, which might tell you why. Often services are designed to do some checks on start up and if they fail, their logic says to fail to start.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of Mosquitto before but a quick look at its project site and its [installer](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/installer/mosquitto.nsi) (NSIS) says that it *is a Windows service.* That installer just runs `mosquitto.exe install` and `mosquitto.exe uninstall` as appropriate.

In general, I'd recommend letting third-party installers do what they do—until proven unreliable. To use their installer, you could create a WiX Bootstrapper project (uses the "burn" package manager; project typically has a bundle.wxs with a Bundle root element).

There could be command-line arguments (standard NSIS or custom) that you want to pass to it, such a silent install.

Comment: I'm already running the mosquitto installer MSI through a Burn EXE. So it'll not be possible to run the mosquitto as an EXE project. Do you suggest any work around techniques to install it as an MSI?

Comment: Well, their success path is their NSIS installer. If you have a need not to use it, you could reimplement it—as a first pass, exactly the same. That would mean custom actions to run `mosquitto.exe install` and `mosquitto.exe uninstall`. If that does do it you, you'd have to see what those command actually do.